# Execute mitmdump as background process in mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal, proxy, mitmproxy

I want to execute mitmdump as a background process from python in Mac. For Windows, I am using the following command

```
START /B mitmdump.exe -q -s execute_proxy.py
```

I want to execute mitmdump in the same manner as it is running in Windows

Answer (score 1):

Use ampersand (`&`) to put command into the background like this:

```
mitmdump -q -s execute_proxy.py &
```